# Issue in Convert UserControl from windows phone 8.1 to universal application 10

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I need your suggestion and help please. I already have a working windows phone 8.1 application and I need to convert it to UWP.

My question is related to usercontrol custom image button: how to convert it and what is the best way to have such control on UWP.

This is my windows phone 8 code:-

**XAML:-**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomizedPopup.ImageButton.ImageButtonControl">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--<Image x:Name="Image" Stretch="Fill"  Width="auto" Grid.Row="0"/>-->
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**CS file :-**

```
namespace CustomizedPopup.ImageButton  
{
public partial class ImageButtonControl : UserControl
{
    public ImageButtonControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ImageSource source;
    public event EventHandler Click;


    Double textfontsize;
    public Double TextFontSize
    {
        get { return textfontsize; }
        set { textfontsize = value; TextBlock.FontSize = textfontsize; }
    }
    public ImageSource Source
    {

        get { return source; }
        set
        {
            source = value;
            System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush myBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush();
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = source;// new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Assets/bg/bg1.jpg/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
            myBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            LayoutRoot.Background = myBrush;

            //Image.Source = source; 
        }
    }

    public ImageSource PressedSource { get; set; }

    string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; TextBlock.Text = text; }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush myBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush();
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = PressedSource;// new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Assets/bg/bg1.jpg/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
        myBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        LayoutRoot.Background = myBrush;

    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);

        System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush myBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush();
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = Source;// new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Assets/bg/bg1.jpg/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
        myBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        LayoutRoot.Background = myBrush;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        //Image.Source = Source;

        System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush myBrush = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush();
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = Source;// new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Assets/bg/bg1.jpg/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        myBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;
        myBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        LayoutRoot.Background = myBrush;

        if (Click != null)
            Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        //Image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For converting Windows 8.1 app to UWP you can use this script

[Powershell script to upgrade V8.1 csproj and manifest to uwp](https://github.com/Win10DevGuideMVA/ProjectUpgradeUtility)

But it will not convert your code.
If talk about code, you can leave XAML as is, but you need changes in C#. 
Replace all calls like

```
OnMouseLeave(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
```

With

```
OnPointerExited(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
```

And ImageBrush is now in Windows.UI.Xaml.Media namespace. Change it also